# How to dynamically create menu in jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm wanting the menu to load the data that comes from the database. This is being static manually, does anyone have any idea how I can do this? Here's my current structure. Anything if you need more code details I can show you
My method:

```
@Composable
private fun DrawerContent(
    scope: CoroutineScope,
    scaffoldState:ScaffoldState,
    navController: NavController
){
    val items = listOf(
            Screen.Entry1,
            Screen.Entry2,
            Screen.Entry3
    )

    Column(modifier= Modifier
        .background(colorResource(id = R.color.pastel_green))
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .fillMaxHeight(),
           horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
        Text(
                "Menu", style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 20.dp,top=20.dp),
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.marron)
        )

        val current by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
        val currentRoute = current?.destination

        items.forEach { screen ->
            var selected = currentRoute?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == screen.route } == true
            val selectedColor = if (selected) colorResource(id = R.color.cinza) else Color.Transparent
            val colorfont = if (selected) colorResource(id = R.color.white) else colorResource(id = R.color.cinza)

            Row(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(32.dp)
                .background(selectedColor)
                .clickable {
                    selected =
                        currentRoute?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == screen.route } == true
                    scope.launch { scaffoldState.drawerState.close() }
                    navController.navigate(screen.route) {
                        // Pop up to the start destination of the graph to
                        // avoid building up a large stack of destinations
                        // on the back stack as users select items
                        popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                            saveState = true
                        }
                        // Avoid multiple copies of the same destination when
                        // reselecting the same item
                        launchSingleTop = true
                        // Restore state when reselecting a previously selected item
                        restoreState = true

                    }
                }) {
                Text(stringResource(screen.resourceString),fontSize = 20.sp,
                        color= colorfont)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Class Screen:

```
sealed class Screen(val route: String, @StringRes val resourceString: Int,@IdRes val resourceId:Int) {
    object Entry1 : Screen("entry1", R.string.entry1, R.id.entry1)
    object Entry2 : Screen("entry2", R.string.entry2, R.id.entry2)
    object Entry3 : Screen("entry3", R.string.entry3,  R.id.entry3)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**solved**
My Code:

```
                        NavHost(
                                navController = navController,
                                // 1st change: Set startDestination to the exact string of route
                                startDestination = "entry${items[0].category_id}/{$ARG_ID}", // NOT "dynamic/1", provide arguments via defaultValue
                        ) {

                            items.forEach { screen ->
                                composable(
                                        route = "entry${screen.category_id}/{$ARG_ID}",
                                        // 2nd change: Set startDestination argument via defaultValue
                                        arguments = listOf(navArgument(ARG_ID) {
                                            type = NavType.IntType; defaultValue =
                                            screen.category_id
                                        }),
                                ) {
                                    entryAbstract.Entry1(id = it.arguments?.getInt(ARG_ID))
                                }
                            }

                        }
companion object
{
    const val ARG_ID = "id"
}
```

My method composable

```
@Composable
private fun DrawerContent(scope: CoroutineScope,scaffoldState:ScaffoldState
,navController: NavController
) {


    Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(colorResource(id = R.color.pastel_green))
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .fillMaxHeight(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(
                "Menu", style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 20.dp, top = 20.dp),
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.marron)
        )

        val current by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
        val currentRoute = current?.destination

        items.forEach { screen ->
            var selected = currentRoute?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == "entry${screen.category_id}/{$ARG_ID}" } == true
            val selectedColor = if (selected) colorResource(id = R.color.cinza) else Color.Transparent
            val colorfont = if (selected) colorResource(id = R.color.white) else colorResource(id = R.color.cinza)

            Row(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(32.dp)
                .background(selectedColor)
                .clickable {
                    selected =
                        currentRoute?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == "entry${screen.category_id}/{$ARG_ID}" } == true
                    scope.launch { scaffoldState.drawerState.close() }
                    navController.navigate("entry${screen.category_id}/${screen.category_id}") {
                        // Pop up to the start destination of the graph to
                        // avoid building up a large stack of destinations
                        // on the back stack as users select items
                        popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                            saveState = true
                        }
                        // Avoid multiple copies of the same destination when
                        // reselecting the same item
                        launchSingleTop = true
                        // Restore state when reselecting a previously selected item
                        restoreState = true

                    }
                }) {
                Text(screen.category_name, fontSize = 20.sp, color = colorfont)
            }
        }
    }
}
```